# Keys and key-stretching when authenticating requests?

Tags: hash, authentication, keys, hmac, sha-256

I'm making a REST application and still a bit confused about this issue. basically, to authenticate incoming requests, I give out userId, issued timestamp,  expiry timestamp (normally 3 months after issue) and the signature for client to use for next requests. for every incoming requests, server will use userId, issued and expiry timestamp and calculate the HMAC using SHA-256 and here, I'm using a global secret key (so, 1 secret key is shared by all requests in an application).

My questions are:

1. I've seen people including http method, url, query params, etc as message payload. what's the downside of my approach of only using userId, issued and expiry timestamp and none of those?
2. Is it recommended to use 1 secret key per user instead of per application?
3. For password hashing, I know we need to use key stretching. Do we need to do the same with message auth? I'm worried that it might be too much a burden for server.

Comment: If your HMAC key is already randomly generated, I don't think it makes sense to do key stretching. If you're computing `K2 = scrypt(K1)`, and both K1 and K2 are 256-bit random keys, then there's no reason for an attacker to try to guess K1. Instead, they can skip the scrypt step by trying to guess K2. It's only when your K1 is shorter or non-random that you gain something by using key stretching.

Comment: So I guess the purpose is to make sure the requests come from who you think they are coming from? In that case you *must* have per-user keys or someone can just swap their userid. Or is the userid also meant to be secret?